# cocoa: is there any way to custom the view(such as ABPeoplePicker View) supplied by Cocoa library

Tags: macos, cocoa, contacts, abaddressbook, abpeoplepickerview

I need to use ABPeoplePickerView to implement my AddressBook application. the view in IB is like this:
[image]

and it's like the following after running:
[image]

I want to delete the search field and add a button(like "add") on the top, but I don't know how to change the view layout. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subclass the view to customize it.

Answer (score 0):

This function finds the search field. Hopefully it may point the way for you to proceed.

```
extension ABPeoplePickerView {
  func searchField () -> NSSearchField?{
    for v in self.subviews[0].subviews {
      if v.isKind(of: NSSearchField.self) { return (v as! NSSearchField) }
    }
    return nil
  }
}
```